# Reload table view on editing UITextView inside UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I have some customised UITableViewCells which contain a UITextView and a set of buttons. The buttons in the cell should be visible only when the user tries to edit the text view in the corresponding cell. 
So, if the user attempts to edit the textview in cell1, then the set of buttons should be visible below the textview in cell1 and the height of cell1 should also be increased.  Now, if the user attempts to edit the textview in cell2, then the set of buttons should be visible below the textview in cell2 and the height of cell2 should also be increased, whereas the buttons in cell1 should get removed and cell size needs to be calculated accordingly.

For this I tried to reload the table view cells from textViewDidBeginEditing:. This is reloading the cells properly and shows/hides the buttons properly in the required cells, but does not allow proper editing of text view. When the user tries to edit with the textview, the tableview reload methods are invoked constantly and not allowing the keyboard to stand for editing.

Is it right to handle reloading from textViewDidBeginEditing: in first place ? is there some better way to do this ? please help.

Comment: put some code that you use in your project

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest that do not reload the entire TableView each time. Instead use the

```
reloadRowsAtIndexPaths
```

method to load only the cell in which you want modifications.

Next, to solve your issue regarding the textView, you could do something like this, declare a class property of bool type, and set it to false. When you reload your cell for the first time, set it to true. Now in the textViewDidBegin editing method, check for this bool. If it is set to true, that means you already have loaded the cell and you do not need to load it again, so in this case do not call the reloadRows method. Else if it is false, reload the rows and set this bool to true. 
Now in the textViewDidEndEditing delegate method, set this bool to false again so that when a user taps on another textView in some other row, it is reloaded properly.

This logic may not be perfect, you may require some tweaking. But it will get the job done

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly make the textfield as firstResponder

```
if buttonsDisplayed == NO {
reload cell
}
if textFieldIsFirstResponder == NO {
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```